# Что нужно написать в html чтобы картинка-ссылка с css отображалась на странице?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть вот этот css код к примеру:

```
body {  
background-image:url(имярисунка.gif);  
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написать такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Имя страницы</title>
<style>
body{
 background-image:url(имя рисунка.gif);
 background-repeat:repeat-y; 
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: 50px 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ну а какой код нужно прописать чтобы в нужном мне месте была картинка? в боди!

Comment: Вот я изменил код надо использавать селектор  background-position

Answer (score 0):

Подключите файл css вот так:
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />

Только ссылку на свой файл css измените. Картинка будет фоном страницы

Comment: картинка по прежнему не отображается! или мне нужно что-то в css изменить? нужно чтобы картинка была бекграундовой в нужном месте на странице!

Comment: тогда надо вставить div

Comment: проверьте, правильно ли вы указали ссылку